# To report Youtube security bug

Tags: security, youtube, bugs

I found security vulnerability/bug on YouTube. I want to report. How can I report it? Is there a quick way?

Answer (score 2):

Being that YouTube is a product of Google, You can report the bug on Google's report security bug, [page](https://www.google.com/appserve/security-bugs/m2/new?rl=&key=)

From the page:

> If you have found a security bug in a Google product and want to
>   report it to us, you've come to the right place. Please fill out the
>   following form and we'll be in touch shortly. If this is a valid
>   vulnerability report, it might also be eligible for a reward as part
>   of our Vulnerability Reward Program. Thanks!